# Spring: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm creating simple web app to display and add rows to my oracle database (Regions table). Sadly I'm getting exception as in title. I've seen similar question related to this unfortunately nothing helped me.

What I'm doing wrong ? I know it's related to transactions. I've annotated Service as `@Transactional`, however it doesn't solved my problem.

If someone could check if `imports` are correct in `Service`.

If something more is needed please leave comment.

> **Exception**

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
    at facade.RegionsDaoImpl.getRegions(RegionsDaoImpl.java:31)
    at facade.RegionServiceImpl.getRegions(RegionServiceImpl.java:27)
    at controllers.RegionsController.listCustomers(RegionsController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> **applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>hr</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>hr</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list> 
                <value>persistence/Regions.hbm.xml</value> 
                <value>persistence/Countries.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>persistence/Locations.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>persistence/Departments.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>persistence/Employees.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>persistence/JobHistory.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>persistence/Jobs.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!--<property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props> 
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

> **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC annotation mechanism-->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />
    <!-- Resolves views choosen for rendering to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/jsp directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="regionsDao" class="facade.RegionsDaoImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="regionService" class="facade.RegionServiceImpl"/> 
</beans:beans>
```

> **RegionsController.java**

```
package controllers;

import facade.RegionService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import persistence.Regions;

@Controller
public class RegionsController {
    @Autowired
    private RegionService regionsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/regions")
    public String listCustomers(Model model) {

        List<Regions> regionsList = regionsService.getRegions();
        model.addAttribute("regionsList", regionsList);
        model.addAttribute("region", new Regions());
        return "regions";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_region")
    public String addRegion(@ModelAttribute Regions r) {
        regionsService.addRegion(r);
        return "redirect:/customers";
    }
}
```

> **RegionService.java   RegionServiceImpl.java**

```
package facade;

import java.util.List;
import persistence.Regions;

public interface RegionService {
    public List<Regions> getRegions();
    public void addRegion(Regions r);
}

/*******************************************/
package facade;

import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import persistence.Regions;


@Service
@Transactional
public class RegionServiceImpl implements RegionService{

    @Autowired
    private RegionsDao regionsDao;

    @Override
    public List<Regions> getRegions() {
        return regionsDao.getRegions();
    }

    @Override
    public void addRegion(Regions r) {
        regionsDao.addRegion(r);
    }

}
```

> **RegionsDao.java RegionsDaoImpl.java**

```
package facade;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import persistence.Regions;

public interface RegionsDao {
    public void addRegion(Regions r);
    public List<Regions> getRegions();
    public void removeRegion(BigDecimal regionId);
}

/**********************************************/
package facade;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import persistence.Regions;

public class RegionsDaoImpl implements RegionsDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addRegion(Regions r) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(r);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Regions> getRegions() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Regions r").list();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeRegion(BigDecimal regionId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this code from `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<beans:bean id="regionsDao" class="facade.RegionsDaoImpl"/>

<beans:bean id="regionService" class="facade.RegionServiceImpl"/>
```

to `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="regionsDao" class="facade.RegionsDaoImpl"/>
```

You don't need `<bean/>` for RegionServiceImpl because you have `@Service` on your service impl  class. In `applicationContext.xml` add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="facade" />
```

In your `RegionServiceImpl` class the import should actually be:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your @Transactional service was not correctly instrumented by Spring AOP system. This can be verified by putting a breakpoint inside transactional method and inspecting the call stack. Spring generates proxy classes with CGLIB so if everything worked correctly you should see some unusual class names (look for "$EnhancerByCGLIB")

Answer (score 0):

In service object you are importing the wrong transactional annotation. The one you are using is java native (EJB), the spring one is: 
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

So, just change this line

import javax.transaction.transactional

with

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

in RegionServiceImpl.